# How to use ssh tags on ssh_config

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, unix, ubuntu-18.04

Hi i'm wondering how to use a previously defined tag in my ssh_config file which looks like this

```
Host myhost
        Hostname myhost.ddns.net

Match user jhonfoo host myhost
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myhost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page states, in relevant part:

> The criteria for the **host** keyword are matched against the target hostname, after any substitution by the **Hostname** or **CanonicalizeHostname** options.  The **originalhost** keyword matches against the hostname as it was specified on the command-line.

Therefore you should `Match user jhonfoo originalhost myhost` instead.